# When editing TextFieldListCell the corresponding class is shown

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have the following code for editing a cell in a ListView:

```
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TextModule>, ListCell<TextModule>>() {
  @Override public ListCell<TextModule> call(ListView<TextModule> param) {
    TextFieldListCell<TextModule> textCell = new TextFieldListCell<TextModule>() {
      @Override public void updateItem(TextModule item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null) {
          setText( item.getSummary());
        }
        else {
          setText(null);
        }
      }
    };
    return textCell;
  }
});
```

Now the problem is, that if I enter any cell within the `ListView` with double click, I can edit the cell, but the property (text which is displayed) is changed to the class definition like `com.test.tools.tbm.model.TextModule@179326d`. Normally it displays a text like "Hello World" or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide a proper string converter for `TextFieldListCell` it will use the default implementation (from `CellUtils`):

```
private static <T> String getItemText(Cell<T> cell, StringConverter<T> converter) {
    return cell.getItem().toString();
}
```

showing in your case `com.test.tools.tbm.model.TextModule@179326d`, as `cell.getItem()` returns an instance of `TextModule`.

So you need to override `toString()` in your `TextModule` class.

```
class TextModule {
    private final String summary;

    public TextModule(String summary){
        this.summary=summary;
    }

    public String getSummary(){ return summary; }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return summary;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively you could provide your own `StringConverter`:

```
    listView.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView(new StringConverter<TextModule>(){

        @Override
        public String toString(TextModule item) {
            return item.getSummary();
        }

        @Override
        public TextModule fromString(String string) {
            return new TextModule(string);
        }

    }));
```